# How do you manipulate CSS with ruby?

Tags: javascript, css, ruby

I am learning ruby now and the one thing that I am having a hard time finding documentation/examples on is how to manipulate CSS with ruby. The first language I learned was Javascript which I would use vanilla JS or Jquery to change CSS attributes, but I can't find anything similar in ruby, am I missing something?

I am finding myself putting in script tags in my HTML to so I can use javascript to change CSS properties. I don't feel like this is good practice if I want to build a ruby app. I want my code to be consistent, so I'm trying to only use ruby.

Can anyone help me out with this? Thank you in advance!

****Also, this is my first post and I noticed that someone down voted this question. In the spirit of improving my presents on this website. Can you also let me know what this question would be down voted?

Comment: Your Ruby code runs on the **server**. You can *generate* CSS with Ruby if you want, but as far as browser-side updates, you're stuck with JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you Pointy! I will look into generating CSS. Following up on your question. Is it bad practice to mix Javascript and ruby in the same project?

Comment: No. It's extremely common for the server-side language to be something other than JavaScript. The two environments (client and server) are fundamentally different.

Comment: Downvote pirates abound. Their goal is not to help you learn, but to discourage you. Of the 1000 great things about SO, this is the one disappointment. Don't take it too hard.